# Is it possible to reference conditional compilation symbol from another project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build, conditional-compilation

In my solution, I have two C# projects:

- The "parent" project defines<sup>1</sup> the following conditional compilation symbol: `X`.
- The "child" project references the parent project.

Is there a way to use the `X` in the **child** project (i.e. `#if X ... #endif`)?

---

*<sup>1</sup> Project Properties / Build / Conditional compilation symbols.*

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly, but there's a rather simple workaround: In your parent project, declare a static method:

```
public static bool Xdefined()
{
#if X
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}
```

Of course, this will do a runtime evaluation and you won't be able i.e. to conditionally exclude large parts of the code, but it can help in many cases. Otherwise, you'll have to also set X for the child (and best set up one solution configuration where all projects have it set and one without.)